# Show that a certain subset of $L^p([0,1])$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Consider $[0,1]$ with its Lebesgue measure. Let $1<p<\infty$ and set
$$\Gamma = \left\{f\in L^p([0,1]): \int_0^1 5f(x)x^3dx \leq \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1 f(x) dx.\right\}$$ Prove that $\Gamma$ is closed in $L^p([0,1])$.

I ran into this problem while working through old qual problems and am pretty stuck. I have been trying to show that $\Gamma^C$ is open, i.e. for all $f \in \Gamma^C$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(f) \subset \Gamma^C$. If we let $f \in \Gamma^C$, then we need to find some $\delta > 0$ such that if $\|f-g\|_p = \left(\int_0^1 |f-g|^p dx\right)^\frac{1}{p} < \delta$, then $g \in \Gamma^C$. My thought was to split up the integral:
$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 g dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 (g -f) dx + \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 f dx < \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^1 (g -f) dx + \int_0^1 5f(x)x^3 dx.$$ However, I'm not sure where to go from here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You just need to show $f\mapsto 5\int f (x) x^3 - \frac{1}{\pi}\int f(x)$ is continuous, which is easy since it's linear.

Comment: I don't see how continuity would help us here. The fact that this map is continuous would tell us that $$\left| 5\int (f(x) - g(x)) x^3 dx - \frac{1}{\pi}\int (f(x)-g(x) dx \right| < \epsilon.$$ However, this doesn't tell us anything about $g$ that lets us say $g\in \Gamma^C$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Let me spell out what Arctic Char probably meant. Define $$G: L^p([0,1])\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, G(f)=\int_0^1 f(x)\left(5x^3-\frac{1}{\pi}\right).$$ By Hölder's inequality this map is continuous and hence $\Gamma=G^{-1}((-\infty,0])$ is closed as it is the preimage of a closed set of a continuous function.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $f_1,f_2,\dots \in \Gamma,$ and $f_n\to f $ in $L^p.$ Then $f_n\to f$ in $L^1.$ Doesn't that imply the given inequality holds for $f?$

Comment: Why does convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in $L^1$?

Comment: @halestorm818 As we are on a finite measure space, this follows from Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Okay, and then we can use Fatou's Lemma to show the desired inequality for f. Thank you!

Comment: I would use DCT to finish.